# Creating a custom control with TextChanged event from code

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I'm currently creating a DLL of a Custom Control Form, using code behind. In this control, I have a TextBox in which I want to create an event for TextChanged that has to be set in the page where they are using the custom control.

> CustomControlForm.cs

This is the code where I create my TextBox:

```
protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox NumberTextBox;
public event EventHandler NumberChanged;

protected override void CreateControls()
{
    base.CreateControls();

    NumberTextBox= new TextBox();
    NumberTextBox.ID = "NumberTextBox";
    NumberTextBox.MaxLength = 9;
    NumberTextBox.Columns = 10;
    NumberTextBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnNumberChanged);
}

public string Number
{
    get
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        return NumberTextBox.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        NumberTextBox.Text = value;
    }
}

protected void OnNumberChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (NumberChanged != null)
    {
        NumberChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

After that, I'm implementing it in another project where I'm trying to set the event TextChanged.

> WebUserControl1.ascx.cs

In that page, there's the following code:

```
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        CustomControlForm.NumberChanged += new EventHandler(NumberTextBox_TextChanged);
    }

    public void NumberTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OtherTextBox.Text = CustomControlForm.Number;
    }
```

For some reason, when I change the value of NumberTextBox, the event NumberTextBox_TextChanged isn't triggered, am I missing something, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When is NumberTextBox being added to the form? Is it being added with the same ID on every postback?

Comment: I add it on WebUserControl1.ascx view, and it does have the same ID on every postback, but when I change the text no postback occurs

Comment: Could it be that `NumberTextBox` does not have `AutoPostBack` set to true?

Comment: Setting the AutoPostBack worked, thanks